# Why doesn't my angular submit function adding empty data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my first time using angular to make POST method calls to my REST APU.
This is the function in my typeCtrl.js file:

```
$scope.submit  = function() {
    alert("add new type [" + $scope.newtype + "]" );
    $http.post("http://192.168.1.115:8080/type/add", { 'type': $scope.newtype}, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}}).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.data);
    });
    $http.get("http://192.168.1.115:8080/type").then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.data);
        $scope.all_types = response.data;
    });
};
```

The `alert("add new type [" + $scope.newtype + "]" );` executes as expected so I know that `$scope.newtype` has a value.

The output from my node.js backend looks like this:

```
POST /type/add 200 2.267 ms - 73
GET /type 200 23.854 ms - 6465
GET /type 304 22.217 ms - -
undefined
{ '{"type":"aaaa"}': '' }
POST /type/add 200 1.863 ms - 73
GET /type 200 26.053 ms - 6508
undefined
{ '{"type":"zzzzzzz"}': '' }
POST /type/add 200 1.734 ms - 73
GET /type 200 25.389 ms - 6551
undefined
{ '{"type":"zzzzzzz"}': '' }
POST /type/add 200 2.142 ms - 73
GET /type 200 25.435 ms - 6594
```

I do not think I am setting up my `data` correctly.  Can anyone please point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do this ...

```
 33     $scope.submit  = function() {
 34         $scope.formdata = "{'type':'"+$scope.newtype+"'}";
 35         alert("add new type [" + $scope.newtype + "]" );
 36         var data = $.param({ type: $scope.newtype });
 37         $http.post("http://192.168.1.115:8080/type/add",
 38             // [{'type': $scope.newtype}],
 39             data,
 40             {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}}).then(function(response) {
 41             console.log(response);
 42             console.log(response.data);
 43         });
 44         $http.get("http://192.168.1.115:8080/type").then(function(response) {
 45             console.log(response);
 46             console.log(response.data);
 47             $scope.all_types = response.data;
 48         });
 49     };
```